# Catching DataAccessExceptions with AOP

Tags: java, spring, exception, aop

I have a webapp using Spring + Hibernate through JPA, Spring is effectively translating all persitence exceptions into variations of `DataAccessException`.

I am now trying to catch these `DataAccessExceptions` in an AOP pointcut like this:

```
@Aspect
public class AspectException {


    @AfterThrowing(pointcut = "within(com.mypackage.dao..*)", throwing = "error")
    public void catchException(Throwable error) {
      MyOwnException e = new MyOwnException("ERROR!", error);
       throw e;
    }
}
```

Now this aspect works if in my DAO I throw a custom exception, but won't work with Spring's `DataAccessExceptions`!

Any idea why this is happenning?

Comment: Actually I find it hard to believe that this should work for one type of exception and not for another, unless your advice parameter is not typed `Throwable` as in your example but of a specific sub-type not matching the `DataAccessException`. Even the [Spring manual](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-advice-after-throwing) mentions `DataAccessException` as a working example for `@AfterThrowing`.

Answer (score 0):

Have you throught about exception translation?

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/jdbc.html#jdbc-SQLExceptionTranslator

Comment: I want to translate all persistence exceptions into one of my own

Comment: Can I ask why you want to translate all exceptions?  What about something like this:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14729227/exception-handling-strategy-with-spring-jpa-jsf

Comment: Also, see this thread:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24736954/spring-data-jpa-hibernate-catch-block-inside-a-transactional-method-is-never

Comment: I want to translate them into an annotated @WebFault exception with Faultbean for a WebService specification. I'll take a look at those links, thanks!